# SAP .NET Connector in SSIS

Tags: ssis, sap-dotnet-connector

I'm working on a Power BI project where I need to connect to SAP RFC within an SSIS project in Visual Studio.

I downloaded the SAP 3.1 connector and the Microsoft Visual C++ dependency, but the .NET framework data provider for MySAP business suite does not come out among the data sources.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.